# Eigenvalues of the commutator of two triangular matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be two $n\times n$ matrices.

Suppose a matrix $X$ exists, which is unitary, and $X^\ast YX$ and $X^\ast ZX$ result in upper triangular matrices.

What are the eigenvalues of $YZ-ZY$? I'm coming up with all zero but not sure entirely why.

Answer (score 2):

$Y = XT_1X^*$ and $Z = XT_2X^*$

$YZ = XT_1T_2X^*$

and

$YZ−ZY = X(T_1T_2 - T_2T_1)X^*$

The eigenvalues of 
$YZ−ZY$ equal the eigenvalues of $(T_1T_2 - T_2T_1)$

since $T_1$ and $T_2$ are both upper Triangular
$T_1T_2$ and $T_2T_1$ are both upper triangular and have identical main diagonals

$(T_1T_2 - T_2T_1)$ is an upper triangular matrix with all $0$'s down the main diagonal
Trace = $0$  and determinant $0.$